# Absolute value of complex exponential

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Can somebody explain to me why the absolute value of a complex exponential is 1? (Or at least that's what my textbook says.)

For example:

$$|e^{-2i}|=1, i=\sqrt {-1}$$

Comment: What is $ j $? $ $

Comment: Oh sorry, it's the electrical engineering way of saying imaginary i. It's a habit I've gotten used to over the past 2 years.

Comment: absolute value of any complex number is always real.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If it is purely complex then you have $e^{xi}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ the absolute value($|a+bi|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$) is then equal to $\sqrt{\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)}=1$

Comment: ah. of course. Should have known that. Thanks!

Comment: It's an identity most people don't remember(I know it took a while for me to start being able to use it).

Comment: Question - shouldn't that be sqrt(cos^2 + sin^2) = 1 ?

Comment: yeah I forgot to add that in. Simplifies to the same thing though.

Comment: Yeah, just checking.

Comment: You can certainly take the square root, but $\sqrt{1} = 1$.

Comment: @ruler501 Not necessarily. It could be equal to -1...

Comment: Isn't it convention to take positive root? Especially with absolute value.

Answer (score 13):

After +1 accepted answer, just an extension on the same...

$$\begin{align}
\left\vert e^{\text{Re}\,+\,i\text{ Im}}\right\vert 
& = \lvert e^\text{Re}\cdot e^{i\text{ Im}} \rvert\\[2ex]
&=\lvert e^{\text{Re}}\rvert\,\cdot \lvert e^{\,i\text{ Im}}\rvert\\[2ex]
&=  e^{\text{Re}}
\end{align}$$

because $ e^{ix} \in S^1,$ and hence, $\lvert e^{i\,\text{Im}}\rvert=1.$

Comment: Is the plus sign correct?

Comment: @Ramen Thank you. $\LaTeX$ is prone to distract from the actual math... It is corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

By Euler's formula, $e^{j\theta}=\cos(\theta)+j\sin(\theta)$, which is a point on the unit circle at an angle of $\theta$. Let $\theta = \frac{-2j}{j} = -2$, so $e^{-2j}$ is one of the points on the unit circle, which of course is one unit from the origin, so $\left|e^{-2j}\right| = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $e^{-2j} = \cos(-2) + j \sin(-2)$ ...

Comment: Any particular reason to use $j$ and not $i$?

Comment: for anyone else wondering, it's probably an engineering thing. In engineering i can be current, whereas j is unused.

Answer (score 2):

When we extend exponential function $f(x)=e^x$ to complex numbers
so that the extension is differentiable, it is the only way to define
$$
f(x+iy)=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)
$$
I hop that it help your question.

One should know that why the Euler formula comes.

Comment: I've always looked at the formula as the obvious result of the taylor series(if you plug in $iy$ it simplifies to $\cos y + i \sin y$) and then the $x$ is obvious from rules for exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

**Definition of absolute value:**
$$\left|a+i\ b\right|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

**Euler's Formula:**
$$e^{i\theta}=cos\ \theta + i\sin\ \theta$$

**Trig Identity:**

$$cos^{2} \theta + sin^{2} \theta = 1$$

**Steps:**
$$ \left|e^{-i2}\right| $$
$$\theta=-2$$
$$\left|e^{i\theta}\right|=\sqrt{\cos^2\ \theta + \sin^2\ \theta}$$
$$\left|e^{i\theta}\right|=\sqrt1$$
$$\left|e^{i\theta}\right|=1$$
$$ \left|e^{-i2}\right| = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide an intuitive understanding, in addition to the previous excellent answers.

Recall that a complex number in Euler’s form can be expressed as $r e^{i \theta}$, in this case, the modulus is 1 and the argument is -2. Graphically, we can visualize complex numbers of modulus 1 as points on a unit circle.

Algebraically, we say that the unitary group of degree 1 is isomorphic to the unit circle, namely $U(1) \cong S^1$