# convergence criteria from real to complex domains?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

It is well known the following function

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1^x} + \frac{1}{2^x} + \frac{1}{3^x} + \frac{1}{4^x} + \cdots
$$

only converges if $x > 1$.

If we now consider $f(z)$ where z is complex, why can we say that the function converges for $Re(z) > 1$?

**What's logic that allows us to simply apply convergence rules to the real part of a complex function's domain?**

*(I am not a trained mathematician so I'd appreciate answers which minimise assumptions about terminology.)*

Comment: That works for this *particular* series because $|n^z| = n^{\operatorname{Re}(z)}$

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series.

Comment: @MartinR so the assumption isn't general .. we have to work it out for every series we're interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by Martin R in the comment, the reason is that absolute convergence of complex series implies convergence and in this case we have that for $z=x+iy$

$$\left|\frac1{n^z}\right|=\frac1{|n^z| }=\frac1{|n^{x}|}$$

indeed

$$|n^z|= |n^x||n^{iy}|=|n^x||e^{iy\log n}|=|n^x|$$

thus the series conveges for $Re(z)=x>1$.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Why does the magnitude of e^ia = 1? That is, e raised to an imaginary number?

Comment: found it - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721784/absolute-value-of-complex-exponential

Comment: @TariqRashid Yes exactly, $ e^{ai}=\cos a + i \sin a$ is a complex number on yhe unit circle, thus $| e^{ai}|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in this topic, but I think my proof is right.

Recall the triangle inequality for complex numbers $x,y$: $$|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$$

Note that $$\vert \frac1{n^z}\vert=\frac1{|e^{\ln(n)a}||e^{\ln(n)bi}|}=\frac1{n^a}$$

Thus, $$|\zeta(z)|=|\zeta(a+bi)|=|\sum_n\frac1{n^{a+bi}}|\le \sum_n\frac1{|n^{a+bi}|}=\sum_n \frac1{n^a} =\zeta(a)$$

Thus, if $\zeta(a)$ converges, $\zeta(a+bi)$ converges as well.