# Why is the radius of the complex unit circle 1 and not 2.71828

Tags: complex-analysis

Considering $e^{i\pi}$ and how rotation by multiplication on the complex plane works, why is the radius of the complex unit circle 1 and not 2.71828? I don't question the fact that the unit circle should have a radius of 1 but in my mind $(1+0i)^1$ should be the starting point of the unit circle and continue from there. I also understand that $(1+0i)^1$ is non-sensical but that doesn't explain $e^{i n}$ sitting on the unit circle.

My mistake was thinking that for a power of $e$ to end up on $-1$ (on the unit circle) by rotation (multiplication) it should start at $1$ and rotate anti-clockwise to -1, forgetting that $e^0=1$.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721784/absolute-value-of-complex-exponential

Comment: If we had a circle of radius other than one, we'd hardly call it a **unit** circle, would we?

Comment: Could you explain why you think it'd be euler's number $e$?  Howe is the base $e$ in $e^{\pi i}$ supposed to be a radius of a circle?

Comment: The unit circle by definition has radius one and passes through the points $(1,0)= 1+0i$ and $(0, i)=0+1i$ and so on.  All the points of the circle are $(x,yi) = x+ yi$ where $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}= 1$.  SO for any point on the circle there is an angle $\theta$ so then the point $(x,yi) = x+yi = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta = (\cos\theta, i\sin \theta)$.  So far this is just trig and the unit circle has radius $1$.  We define $\cos\theta + i\sin \theta$ to be what $e^{i\theta}$ equals.  $|e^{i\sin\theta}|=1$ and $|e^{i\sin\theta}|\ne e$ and I can't see why you'd think it would.

Comment: I guess what you are thinking is $|e^{i\pi}|$ ought to equal $|e| =e$ but instead $|e^{i\pi}| = 1$.  It's actually hard why you think $|e^M|$ should ever be $e$.  After all $|e^2|=|e|^2 \ne |e|$ and $|e^{319}|\ne e$ either.  So why should $|e^{i\pi}|$.   $i \pi \ne 1$ (not even *close*) so no reason to think $|e^{i\pi}|=e$.  Indeed $e^{i\pi} = -1$ and so $|e^{i\pi}| = |-1| =1$.

Comment: Thank you @fleablood that is exactly the answer I was looking for. $sin$, $cos$ and their relation to $x$, $y$ and $e$ opened my eyes.

Comment: What connection do you make between $e^{i\pi}=-1$ and $2.71828$ (besides the fact that $e=2.71828$) ? What do you mean by "continue from there", can you give an equation ? Sorry but your question is pretty confuse.

Comment: @fleablood $e^0=1$

Comment: Right.  $e^0=1$ and $e^{2\pi i} = 1$ and $e^{\theta i} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.  And every single $|e^{i\theta}|=1$.  *NONE* of them are $|e^{\theta i}| = e$.  Not one.

Comment: My confusion revolves around the fact that when you multiply a complex number with another complex number it rotates around $[0,0]$ so if you multiply a complex number with itself, i.e. raised to a power it should do the same. For that to happen the radius should be equal to the number itself on the real number line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the complex numbers, the distance between two points is the modulus of their difference.

As $|e^{i\theta}-0|=1$, $e^{i\theta}$ sits on the trigonometric circle. And by Euler's formula, you see that

$$x+iy=e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$ matches the parametric equations of that circle,

$$\begin{cases}x=\cos\theta,\\y=\sin\theta.\end{cases}$$

Comment: $e^{i \pi}$ sits on the unit circle, so the radius of $e^{i \pi}$ and all its exponents [should?] sit on the unit circle. But I get it now. If I wasn't misguided I wouldn't have had to ask the question.

Comment: @dataphile: why do you focus on $e^{i\pi}$ ? This is just $-1$, a real number, and $(-1)^n=\pm1$.

Comment: I'm dealing with trigonometry so $e^{i \pi}$ keeps popping up. I just needed to develop an intuition about it so that I can reason about it.

Comment: $e^{i\pi} = -1$.  A weird, but very well known fact.  And $|e^{i\pi}| = |-1| = 1$.  It sits on the unit circle.  .... And you know what *doesn't* sit any the unit circle?  $e^1 = e=2.718$.  That does not sit one the unit circle.  ($1\ne \theta i$ for any real $\theta$ so $e^1$ is *not* on the unit circle.  The unit circle is $C_1= \{e^{i\theta}|\theta\in \mathbb R\}=\{\cos \theta + i\sin \theta|\theta \in \mathbb R$.   And, low and behold, $e\not \in C$.  It just plain aint.)

Comment: @dataphile: sorry but I think that you confuse $e^{i\theta}$, which pops up as the equation of a circle, and $e^{i\pi}$ which is the constant $-1$ and IMO does not occur so often in relation with circles. In particular, a circle equation is rarely written $e^{i\pi x}$.

Comment: You're right @YvesDaoust. Thanks for that.

Comment: I'm dealing with integer number theory, so I use $sin(\pi x)$ often.