# $\left|\frac{\sin(nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}\right| \leq n$

Tags: complex-analysis

[I found a solution but I'm not sure how they got the last few steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohuPE.png)

Clarification would be awesome!
Thanks

Comment: They used $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, which justifies grouping the exponentials.

Comment: Can you please show me some more steps? I'm still having trouble seeing it.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We proceed with mathematical induction in the following form<sup>f1</sup>:

- we prove that $\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}n\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)}\right|=\left|1+e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}+...+e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right|$,
- we prove that $n=1+\left|e^{i\theta}\right|+\left|e^{i2\theta}\right|+...+\left|e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right|$,
- from $\left|1+e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}+...+e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right|\le1+\left|e^{i\theta}\right|+\left|e^{i2\theta}\right|+...+\left|e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right|$, we deduce $\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}n\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)}\right|\le n$.

We know that

$~~~~~1+r+r^{2}+...+r^{n}=\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$

For $r=e^{i\theta}$,

$
\begin{align}
~~~~~\left|1+e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}+...+e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right|&=\left|\frac{1-e^{in\theta}}{1-e^{i\theta}}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{-e^{in\theta/2}\left(e^{in\theta/2}-e^{-in\theta/2}\right)}{-e^{i\theta/2}\left(e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}\right)}\right|\\
&=\left|\frac{e^{in\theta/2}}{e^{i\theta/2}}\right|\left|\frac{\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{in\theta/2}-e^{-in\theta/2}\right)}{\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\theta/2}-e^{-i\theta/2}\right)}\right|\\
&=\left|e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta/2}\right|\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}n\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)}\right|
&\text{by }\sin\left(\theta\right)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}\right)
\end{align}
$

is equivalent to $\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}n\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)}\right|~\left(\#\right)$, because $\left|e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta/2}\right|=1$. Generally we know that $\left|k.e^{ix}\right|=k~~$<sup>f2</sup>.

For $\color{#592720}{k=1}$ and $x=\theta,\ 2\theta,\ ...,\ \left(n-1\right)\theta$ in $\left|k.e^{ix}\right|=k$ we have

$~~~~~1+\left|e^{i\theta}\right|+\left|e^{i2\theta}\right|+...+\left|e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right| = \overbrace{1+1+...+1}^{\text{n times}} = n~\left(\#\#\right).$

From Triangle Inequality we have

$~~~~~\left|1+e^{i\theta}+e^{i2\theta}+...+e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right|\le1+\left|e^{i\theta}\right|+\left|e^{i2\theta}\right|+...+\left|e^{i\left(n-1\right)\theta}\right|,$

which is equivalent to $\left|\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}n\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\theta\right)}\right|\le n$ after plugging $\left(\#\right)$ and $\left(\#\#\right)$.

---

<sup>1.This answer is just the clarification of the image linked in the question.</sup> 
<sup>2.See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721784/absolute-value-of-complex-exponential#answer-721785) for proof.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! That was super clear.